# Strange Error message when implementing an image downloader in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm programming a simple image downloader that loads up a preset image on the screen. Nothing special, and I'm using NSURLConnections to show the image (it's an assignment, so I'm required to use NSURLConnections), but trying to build it gives me this message:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ImageModel", referenced from:


   objc-class-ref-to-ImageModel in ImageDownloaderKSViewController.o


ld: symbol(s) not found


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

"ImageModel" is the class that has the NSURLConnections methods in it. And initializing it automatically calls a "didFinishDownloading" method that is in the view controller, which makes the UIImage equal the image that ImageModel has. I have no idea what the error message means, and it doesn't point to a particular line in the code. Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a linker error. It means that the linker (ld) cannot find the class definition of ImageModel. You forgot to add the ImageModel.m implementation file to the target.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with the initWithFrame method that is normally in UIView? It was in ImageModel, but I replaced it with an init method of my own.

Comment: Okay. I looked at the code, and you were right. I had originally called the imageview picview, but I forgot to change it when I changed the name. Thanks!